# Where is C library?

Tags: perl, configure, msys, mingw-w64

I tried to configure `perl-5.18.2`.

In checking C library phase, I got following messages.

```
Checking for GNU C Library...
You are not using the GNU C Library

I can use /mingw/bin/nm to extract the symbols from your C libraries. This
is a time consuming task which may generate huge output on the disk (up
to 3 megabytes) but that should make the symbols extraction faster. The
alternative is to skip the 'nm' extraction part and to compile a small
test program instead to determine whether each symbol is present. If
you have a fast C compiler and/or if your 'nm' output cannot be parsed,
this may be the best solution.

You probably shouldn't let me use 'nm' if you are using the GNU C Library.

Shall I use /mingw/bin/nm to extract C symbols from the libraries? [y] /mingw/bi
n/x86_64-w64-mingw32-nm.exe

I can't seem to find your C library.  I've looked in the following places:

        /lib
        /usr/lib

None of these seems to contain your C library. I need to get its name...

Where is your C library?
```

Where is my C library?

I've tried /mingw/bin/nm.exe too.

Comment: Why are you seeing Linux "issues" i.e. /lib /usr/lib in a Windows environment? sounds like the "first" bug you need to fix first

Comment: / works fine in context of Perl and other cross my platform software. That is a red herring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.18.2/README.win32:

> The INSTALL file in the perl top-level has much information that is only relevant to people building Perl on Unix-like systems. In particular, you can safely ignore any information that talks about "Configure".

Instead, follow the instructions in the README.win32 file.